# Django Jquery button "pick a post"

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, django, django-views

In Django, I have a button "pick" as follows:

```
<button class="click" id ="click" data-id="{{ Post.id }}" class="btn btn-mini btn-primary" type="button">Pick</button>
```

inside this HTML forloop displaying posts:

```
{% for Post in latest_posts %}  

{{Post.id }}
{{Post.author}}
{{Post.title}}
//button comes here.

{% endfor %}
```

My jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#click').click(function (){
  console.log("create post is working!")
  var pickid;
  pickid = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.post('create_date/', {pickid: pickid}, function(data){
        alert('Button click recorded.')
      });    
})
  });
```

and my view:

```
def record_button_click(request, *args, **kwargs):

if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
    id = request.POST.get('pickid')
    response_data = {}
    form=Pick(post=id,user=request.user)
    response_data = {}
    form.save()

    response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response_data),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
else:
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

With this code, The idea is to save information to the pick table when the user clicks the button "pick":

```
class Pick(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    post=models.ForeignKey(Post)
    pick_date = models.DateTimeField('date picked',default=datetime.datetime.now())
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hard to tell, because you didn't say what is happening. But one issue is that you can't have more than one HTML element with the same ID. Drop the id and bind the jQuery listener on the class, ie `.click`.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman ,this solves one issue! I still get this error in the console: `POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/create_date/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)` `XHR finished loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/create_date/"` and I got nothing stored in the DB

Comment: You should look in your browser's developer tools, the Network tab should show you the actual error message being sent by the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the elements wrong in my code:

- @DanielRoseman: Drop the id and bind the jQuery listener on the class.
- in the Jquery code: add `{pickid: pickid},` to the `$.post` method
- in the view code change the following line: `form=Pick(post_id=id,user=request.user)`

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding a `{% csrf_token %}` for the POST. Either do that or have a `@csrf_exempt` in the views docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#utilities). Hope that helps.